# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot a graph using `matplotlib.pyplot` in Python but getting an error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'list'

in the second-to-last line.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#constants
mUn0 = 1350
Vcat = 18000000
n = 2 * pow(10,16)
e = 1.6 * pow(10,-19)

#variable
E = 1000
d = []
f = []

for i in range(1,E):
    j = log(n*e*mUn0) + log(i) - 0.5 * log(1+pow((mUn0*i/Vcat),2))
    f.append(j)
    d.append(log(i))
plt.xlabel('E')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.subplot(f,d,'bo')
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: in second last line 
plt.subplot(f,d,'bo')

Comment: as is says, you have to pass in something that can be converted to an int for `plt.subplot`. since `f and d` are both lists, it will cause an error. try iterating through `zip(f,d)` and passing each element as parameters

Comment: i didn't get your answer can you just edit what the code as u have said here

Comment: no need, @BlivetWidget's answer addresses the problem way better

Answer (score 1):

`pyplot.subplot()` requires `subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)`, all three options are integers.

Matplotlib is trying to cast your `f` and `d` lists to integer type and failing.

Comment: then how i will just do this

Comment: provide valid arguments from the list, like `f[0]` and `d[0]`, if you want the first elements of those lists. It's not clear from your code what you want the subplot to look like, so I can't provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of small issues.  You have to use `plt.plot()` to plot, and you can't just use `log`, you need `np.log()` or to import the `math` module and then use `math.log()`.  I noted the lines I changed with `#FIXED`

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#constants
mUn0 = 1350
Vcat = 18000000
n = 2 * pow(10,16)
e = 1.6 * pow(10,-19)

#variable
E = 1000
d = []
f = []

for i in range(1,E):
    j = np.log(n*e*mUn0) + np.log(i) - 0.5 * np.log(1+pow((mUn0*i/Vcat),2))  #FIXED
    f.append(j)
    d.append(np.log(i)) #FIXED
plt.xlabel('E')
plt.ylabel('V')
plt.subplot(2,1,2) #not needed, but maybe a holdover from full code
plt.plot(f,d,'bo') #FIXED
plt.show()
```

That takes care of the syntax errors.  Using a subplot works with one plot but you don't need it, so I don't know what type of logic error that is (do you want two plots?)

Comment: @YogeshYadav you bet.  Even though it resulted in an error in this case, major kudos to you for using the 'import as' paradigm.  Too many people import everything into the global namespace.